# What is the little o-notation here

Tags: taylor-expansion

Here is the expression:

I want to find $o(?)$ at the end of the expansion ;

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right) \cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{x^{6}-1}=\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right) \cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}-x^{3} \cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{6}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
=&\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right) \cdot\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3}}{3 !}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{4}}{4 !}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)\right)-x^{3} \cdot\left(1-\frac{\frac{1}{x^{6}}}{2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^{6}}\right)\right) \\
=&\left(x^{3}-x^{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right) \cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2 \cdot x^{2}}+\frac{1}{6 \cdot x^{3}}+\frac{1}{24 \cdot x^{4}}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)\right)-x^{3} \cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{2 \cdot x^{6}}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^{6}}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

I've tried to expand the brackets, but I've arrived to :
$$
x^{3}o\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)-x^{2}o\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)+\frac{1}{2} xo\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)-x^{3}o\left(\frac{1}{x^{6}}\right)
$$
which is:
$$ \begin{array}{l}
o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\\ o\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\\
+o\left(\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right) \\
+o\left(\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)
\end{array}
$$
And when $
x \rightarrow \infty
$ you have that $o(1/x^3)$$\subset$$o(1/x^2)$ $\subset$$o(1/x)$
so the final answer of $o$ should be $o(1/x)$ but in my textbook it's $o(1/x^3)$.

So how it's  $o(1/x^3)$?

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. Your original expression has a limit of 1/6 as x goes to infinity. So wouldn't that actually make it o(x) as x->infinity?

Comment: You would take more terms in the series to get the answer expanded to something more accurate than $o(1/x)$.  @bonsoon ... yes, there are terms in addition to the error terms Elie asks about.

Comment: @GEdgar- so the final answer should be $o(1/x^3)$ or $o(1/x)$?